# how can i restrict user that have not pay not to have access to quiz section

Tags: django

```
class QuizTake(FormView):
form_class = QuestionForm
template_name = 'question.html'
result_template_name = 'result.html'
single_complete_template_name = 'single_complete.html'

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
    if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
        raise PermissionDenied

    try:
        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated()
    except TypeError:
        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated

    if self.logged_in_user:
        self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user,
                                                    self.quiz)
    else:
        self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()

    if self.sitting is False:
        return render(request, self.single_complete_template_name)

    return super(QuizTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.logged_in_user:
        self.question = self.sitting.get_first_question()
        self.progress = self.sitting.progress()
    else:
        self.question = self.anon_next_question()
        self.progress = self.anon_sitting_progress()

    if self.question.__class__ is Essay_Question:
        form_class = EssayForm
    else:
        form_class = self.form_class

    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(QuizTake, self).get_form_kwargs()

    return dict(kwargs, question=self.question)

def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.logged_in_user:
        self.form_valid_user(form)
        if self.sitting.get_first_question() is False:
            return self.final_result_user()
    else:
        self.form_valid_anon(form)
        if not self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]:
            return self.final_result_anon()

    self.request.POST = {}

    return super(QuizTake, self).get(self, self.request)
```

**the code above is my views**
please i want to give restriction for user who have not pay not to be able to access the exam section.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
```

class Quiz(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(
    verbose_name=_("Title"),
    max_length=60, blank=False)

description = models.TextField(
    verbose_name=_("Description"),
    blank=True, help_text=_("a description of the quiz"))

url = models.SlugField(
    max_length=60, blank=False,
    help_text=_("a user friendly url"),
    verbose_name=_("user friendly url"))

category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category, null=True, blank=True,
    verbose_name=_("Category"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

random_order = models.BooleanField(
    blank=False, default=False,
    verbose_name=_("Random Order"),
    help_text=_("Display the questions in "
                "a random order or as they "
                "are set?"))

max_questions = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Max Questions"),
    help_text=_("Number of questions to be answered on each attempt."))

answers_at_end = models.BooleanField(
    blank=False, default=False,
    help_text=_("Correct answer is NOT shown after question."
                " Answers displayed at the end."),
    verbose_name=_("Answers at end"))

exam_paper = models.BooleanField(
    blank=False, default=False,
    help_text=_("If yes, the result of each"
                " attempt by a user will be"
                " stored. Necessary for marking."),
    verbose_name=_("Exam Paper"))
```

**this is my models please any suggestion**
i have searched google but all i got does not work for me,so for each quiz there will be permission before user can have access to it,like meet some requirements before they can actually do the quiz.

Comment: You can extend the user class or make a profile table that relates back to the user ID. Extending to put an attribute like `paid`. Then in the view.py just check to make sure they've paid. [Here's a tutorial on extending Django user model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

Comment: Ok thanks so much but the quiz is actually not one it can get upto like 20 different quiz and user need to pay for each before taking it

Comment: This is called "many to many" relation. You need an additional table (model) to represent (user_id, quiz_id) and some other attrs like `paid`, `taken` and so on. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/